# Multiple websites on a single EC2 instance (or VPC step-by-step guide!)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address, amazon-vpc

I know how to have [multiple domains run from a single EC2 instance](http://calebogden.com/multiple-websites-amazon-ec2-linux-virtual-hosts/) using [apache VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), but I'm interested in having multiple IP addresses assigned for each instance.

Amazon recently added this feature. It seems that, for this to work, I have to define a VPC instance instead of the classic EC2 instances. To begin with, I wonder if it's even possible to migrate an existing EC2 instance to the VPC type in order to take advantage of this.

Also, the doc is very confusing & there are many cryptic terms that I'm not used to (network interfaces, VPC, Route tables, DHCP options, etc...), I'm *totally* lost!

**My question is: is there an easy to follow, step-by-step, tutorial that can help me setup/configure a VPC instance and assign multiple IP addresses to it?**

I googled a lot but didn't find any, I'm fairly familiar with EC2 / S3 / RDS, but VPC is a completely different beast!